# Simple XML parsing example for Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I am trying to get a list of keys and values for the Response object so I can turn them into a Hash, but I'm having problems understanding Nokogiri. The XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml>
<Response>
    <Name>Anonymous</Name>
    <ExternalDataReference></ExternalDataReference>
    <EmailAddress>hi guys</EmailAddress>
    <IPAddress>blahblah</IPAddress>
    <Status>0</Status>
..... (approximately 30 more elements within each response tag)
</Response>
(approximately 75 more response tags in the document)
```

My goal was to get something like this for each Response:

```
Name: Anonymous
ExternalDataReference:
EmailAddress: hi guys
IPAddress: blahblah
```

My code so far:

```
f=File.open("./stufftoparse.xml")
doc = Nokogiri::XML(f)
puts "#{doc.xpath("//Response").keys} \n#{doc.xpath("//Response").values}"
```

I know the code above doesnt work, but I dont quite get how to get the elements in the Response tag (I dont think they are attributes of the Response because they are within their own XML). Can someone explain how to do this? Please note, I have spent some time reading the Nokogiri docs and couldn't find much relating to XPATH examples.

**Additional question:**
How can I split the Responses apart so that I have something like this?

```
Response1:
Name: Anonymous
ExternalDataReference:
EmailAddress: hi guys
IPAddress: blahblah

Response2:
Name: Anonymous
ExternalDataReference:
EmailAddress: hi guys
IPAddress: blahblah
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution can be easier to see if you try it in steps.

Example XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml>
  <foo>
    <goo>a</goo>
    <hoo>b</hoo>
  </foo>
  <foo>
    <goo>c</goo>
    <hoo>d</hoo>
  </foo>
</xml>
```

The syntax `//foo` selects all the `foo` elements.

```
> puts doc.xpath("//foo")
<foo>
  <goo>a</goo>
  <hoo>b</hoo>
</foo>
<foo>
  <goo>c</goo>
  <hoo>d</hoo>
</foo>
```

Nokogiri returns nodes as a `NodeSet` like this:

```
> puts doc.xpath("//foo").class
Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet
```

A `NodeSet` is enumerable; you can use methods such as `each`, `map`, etc.

```
> puts doc.xpath("//foo").kind_of?(Enumerable)
true
```

This `NodeSet` contains two `foo` elements:

```
> doc.xpath("//foo").each{|e| puts e.class }
Nokogiri::XML::Element
Nokogiri::XML::Element
```

The syntax `//foo/*`    selects the `foo` elements' child elements:

```
> puts doc.xpath("//foo/*")
<goo>a</goo>
<hoo>b</hoo>
<goo>c</goo>
<hoo>d</hoo>
```

To print an element's info, see [Nokogiri/XML/Node](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node) documentation; the two methods you'll likely want are `name` and `text`.

Solution for you:

```
> doc.xpath("//foo/*").each{|e|
  puts "#{e.name}:#{e.text}" 
}
goo:a
hoo:b
goo:c
hoo:d
```

For your second question, you're essentially asking:

1. for each `foo` element, get its child elements
2. for each child element, print the name and text

Solution for you:

```
> doc.xpath("//foo").each_with_index{|parent_elem, parent_count| 
  puts "Parent #{parent_count + 1}"
  parent_elem.elements.each{|child_elem|
    puts "#{child_elem.name}:#{child_elem.text}"
  }
}
```

Comment: Looking at your example I tried to figure out how to separate the Response from each other, yet the wildcard seems to get all children regardless of whether they are in a different Response tag. Is there a way to get only one Response at a time? maybe something like getting "//Response" then looping through the return with "//Response/*" to get only the elements of a single response?

Comment: @Rilcon42 Add what you're trying to do to your original question, so I can understand what output you want, and I'll add more to the answer.

Comment: I updated the question, I really appreciate you taking the time to look at this.